# Question on maximal left ideals.

Tags: banach-algebras, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Suppose I have a unital Banach algebra $A$ and a maximal left ideal $L$ and an element $a$ such that $La\subset{}L$. I want to show that there exists (uniqueness is easy) some complex $\lambda$ such that $a-\lambda{}1$ is in $L$.

So far I have a feeling its something to do with the spectrum. I tried proving that if $a$ is not invertible then $a$ must be in $L$ which would be enough. I'm not sure if this is even true though. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the quotient Banach space $A/L$.  Since $La\subset L$, we can consider $a$ to act as a bounded operator on $A/L$ by right multiplication.  The spectrum of this operator must be nonempty, so there exists some $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $a-\lambda1$ is not invertible as an operator on $A/L$.

Now $A/L$ is also a left $A$-module, and the right multiplication of $a$ on it is a left $A$-module homomorphism.  Since $L$ is maximal, $A/L$ is moreover a simple left $A$-module.  So by Schur's lemma, every endomorphism of $A/L$ as a left $A$-module is either zero or invertible.  Since right multiplication by $a-\lambda1$ is not invertible, it is therefore $0$, which means $a-\lambda 1\in L$.